# Cyclic Galois Group Subgroup Fixfields

Tags: galois-theory, splitting-field, galois-extensions

Setting up a Galios Group with the roots of $x^7 - 1$ in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$.  From Pinter's A Book of Abstract Algebra, Chapter 32.

Let: $p(x)=x^7 - 1$

$x^7 - 1 = (x-1)(x^6+x^5+x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1)$.

Let: $q(x) = x^6+x^5+x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1$.

Let: $\omega$ be any root of $q(x)$.

The splitting field ("root field" in this book) of $q(x)$ is $\mathbb{Q}$($\omega$).

FIND the members of $\;Gal(\Bbb Q(\omega)/\Bbb Q)$ (or "$Gal(\Bbb Q(\omega):\Bbb Q)$" in the book I'm using).

Then FIND the subgroups of $\;Gal(\Bbb Q(\omega)/\Bbb Q)$ and FIND the associated fixfields.

$q(x)$ is the minimal polynomial of $\Bbb Q(\omega)$ over $\Bbb Q$.  $p(x)$ is seventh order and is prime, so the degree of $\Bbb Q(\omega)$ over $\Bbb Q$ is $7-1=6$.  Therefore, there exist six automorphisms h:$\Bbb Q(\omega)$ to $\Bbb Q(\omega)$ which fix $\Bbb Q$.  Therefore $\Bbb Gal(\Bbb Q(\omega)/\Bbb Q)$ has six elements.

All members of $\;Gal(\Bbb Q(\omega)/\Bbb Q)$ are automorphisms which permute $\;\omega$, $\;\omega^2, \omega^3,  \omega^4, \omega^5, \omega^6$ and fix $\Bbb Q$.  Let h be any member of $\;Gal(\Bbb Q(\omega)/\Bbb Q)$.  Each automorphism is fully determined by the choice of h($\omega$) (this is true only because $x^7-1$ has a prime order).  The members of $\;Gal(\Bbb Q(\omega)/\Bbb Q)$:

\begin{matrix}
\epsilon\\
\end{matrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
\omega&\omega^2&\omega^3&\omega^4&\omega^5&\omega^6\\
\omega&\omega^2&\omega^3&\omega^4&\omega^5&\omega^6\\
\end{bmatrix}

\begin{matrix}
\alpha\\
\end{matrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
\omega&\omega^2&\omega^3&\omega^4&\omega^5&\omega^6\\
\omega^2&\omega^4&\omega^6&\omega&\omega^3&\omega^5\\
\end{bmatrix}

\begin{matrix}
\beta\\
\end{matrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
\omega&\omega^2&\omega^3&\omega^4&\omega^5&\omega^6\\
\omega^3&\omega^6&\omega^2&\omega^5&\omega&\omega^4\\
\end{bmatrix}

\begin{matrix}
\gamma\\
\end{matrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
\omega&\omega^2&\omega^3&\omega^4&\omega^5&\omega^6\\
\omega^4&\omega&\omega^5&\omega^2&\omega^6&\omega^3\\
\end{bmatrix}

\begin{matrix}
\delta\\
\end{matrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
\omega&\omega^2&\omega^3&\omega^4&\omega^5&\omega^6\\
\omega^5&\omega^3&\omega&\omega^6&\omega^4&\omega^2\\
\end{bmatrix}

\begin{matrix}
\zeta\\
\end{matrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
\omega&\omega^2&\omega^3&\omega^4&\omega^5&\omega^6\\
\omega^6&\omega^5&\omega^4&\omega^3&\omega^2&\omega\\
\end{bmatrix}

$\;Gal(\Bbb Q(\omega)/\Bbb Q)$ is cyclic, with $\beta$ as a generator (maybe some others can act as generator as well, I didn't check them all).

The proper subgroups of $\;Gal(\Bbb Q(\omega)/\Bbb Q)$ consist of one isomorphic to $\Bbb Z_2$ and one isomorphic to $\Bbb Z_3$.  The degree of $\Bbb Q(\omega)$ over $\Bbb Q$ is six.  The number of elements in any subgroup $H$ is equal to the degree of $\Bbb Q(\omega)$ over the fixfield of $H$.

And vice-versa, so since $\Bbb Z_2$ has two elements, the degree of $\Bbb Q(\omega)$ over the fixfield associated with the subgroup isomorphic to $\Bbb Z_2$ is two.  Similarly for the other fixfield, with a degree of three.

What I'm not understanding is via the definion of a fixfield:

Letting $H$ be a subgroup of $\;Gal(\Bbb Q(\omega)/\Bbb Q)$, and letting h be any member of $H$, the fixfield associated with $H$ is defined as:

{$x\in\Bbb Q(\omega) : h(x)=x\;\forall\;h\in\;H$}

$\alpha(x)$≠$x$ for any $x=\omega^n$ (n=1,2,3,4,5,6)

$\beta(x)$≠$x$ for any $x=\omega^n$ (n=1,2,3,4,5,6)

$\gamma(x)$≠$x$ for any $x=\omega^n$ (n=1,2,3,4,5,6)

$\delta(x)$≠$x$ for any $x=\omega^n$ (n=1,2,3,4,5,6)

$\zeta(x)$≠$x$ for any $x=\omega^n$ (n=1,2,3,4,5,6)

Only the identity element fixes $\;\omega$, $\;\omega^2, \omega^3,  \omega^4, \omega^5, \omega^6$.

That leads to my question.

Since $h(x)$≠$x\;\forall\;h\in\;H$ except $h=\epsilon$, then as long as any subgroup contains any h≠$\epsilon$ then the fixfield would be $\;\Bbb Q$.  That doesn't seem right though, and it contradicts the above, as [$\Bbb Q(\omega)$ :$\Bbb Q$)] is six.

I've done a similar problem with  $Gal(\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt2, \sqrt3, \sqrt5)/\mathbb{Q})$ but in that case, I was able to multiply the extension elements to obtain elements such as $\sqrt15$ which are members of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt2, \sqrt3, \sqrt5)$ but not members of $\Bbb Q$.  In the current problem, $\omega^n\omega^m$ = $\omega^k$ (k=0,1,2,3,4,5 or 6) for any integers n and m.

I tried setting up intermediate subfields such as $Q(i)$ or $Q(cos(2\pi/7))$ but those don't even seem to be actual subfields.  I can't isolate $i$ from $Q(cos(2\pi/7)-sin(2\pi/7))$ without assuming square roots exist for elements.

Comment: There are many elements in $\mathbf Q(\omega)$ other than powers of $\omega$. Don't be so focused on seeing what fixes $\omega$ only.  For instance, $\omega + \omega^2 + \omega^4$ is fixed by $\alpha$.

Comment: Your description of the automorphisms is very tedious.  An automorphism $\alpha$ such that $\alpha(\omega) = \omega^2$ automatically has $\alpha(\omega^k) = \omega^{2k}$ for all $k$, so there is no real need to write out *all* of those powers.

Comment: Before I posted this, I looked up "fixfield" and didn't come up with much, but now another post "Computing the Galois group of polynomials x^n−a ∈ Q[x]" came up so I'll look at that.

Comment: The term "root field" and "splitting field" do not strictly speaking refer to the same concept in general.  A "root field" of an irreducible polynomial $f(x)$ over $F$ is $F(r)$ where $r$ is one root of $f(x)$.  This field is unique up to isomorphism over $F$.  A "splitting field" of a polynomial $g(x)$ over $F$ is a field generated over $F$ by a full set of roots of $g(x)$.  For example, one root field of $x^4 - 2$ over $\mathbf Q$ is $\mathbf Q(\sqrt[4]{2})$. Another is $\mathbf Q(i\sqrt[4]{2})$.  Neither is a splitting field of $x^4 - 2$ over $\mathbf Q$.

Comment: In your case, $\mathbf Q(\omega)$ is both a root field and splitting field of $q(x)$.

Comment: Got it.  $\omega+\omega^6$ is fixed by $\zeta$ etc.  Sorry for the overlong post - I spent a couple days writing it, hoping I'd figure it out myself during the process.